# Generate list month 1 year above from current month

Tags: date, dart, logic

Currently I want to create function to generate list 1 year above (for example the current month is august 2021, I want to create list from july 2021 - august 2020) any recommend class or built-in function in dart/ flutter?

this is the current code

```
void getListOfMonthAYear() {
  List<String> months = [];
  Map<int, String> listOfMonth = {
    1: 'January',
    2: 'February',
    3: 'March',
    4: 'April',
    5: 'May',
    6: 'June',
    7: 'July',
    8: 'August',
    9: 'September',
    10: 'October',
    11: 'November',
    12: 'December'
  };
  DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
  int listMonthFor1Year = DateTime.monthsPerYear;
  int currentMonth = DateTime.now().month;
  for (int i = 0; i < listMonthFor1Year; i++) {
    print(listOfMonth[currentMonth - i]);
  }
}
```

After january, the list become null (ya because the month below 1 is not found).

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.monthsPerYear; i++) { print(listOfMonth[(currentMonth - 1 - i) % 12 + 1]); }`.  You could remove the `+ 1` at the end if you used a zero-indexed `List` instead of a `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  getMonthAYearFromCurrent().forEach(print);
  // August 2021
  // July 2021
  // June 2021
  // May 2021
  // April 2021
  // March 2021
  // February 2021
  // January 2021
  // December 2020
  // November 2020
  // October 2020
  // September 2020
}

List<String> getMonthAYearFromCurrent({int length = 12}) {
  const listOfMonth = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ];

  final currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final months = <String>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final yearInt = currentDate.year - (0 - (currentDate.month - i) + 12) ~/ 12;
    final monthInt = (currentDate.month - i - 1) % 12;
    months.add('${listOfMonth[monthInt]} $yearInt');
  }

  return months;
}
```

Comment: yeah , cool , that's what iam looking for , thank you